# prepopulating a database not working in android

Tags: java, android, android-room

I need to prepopulate a database table using

```
Room.databaseBuilder(appContext, AppDatabase.class, "Sample.db")
    .createFromAsset("database/myapp.db")
    .build()
```

for doing this I have created a myapp.db from DB Browser for SQLite

have kept file inside assets/database folder, but it's running successfully without any error and no data is available offline.
why it's not giving any error? I tried changing the asset path in function but still, neither any error nor any local database is coming

when I am opening .db file in DB Browser for SQLite, it is opening correctly
Please help

Comment: `createFromAsset (String databaseFilePath)` `databaseFilePath` not `sqlScriptPath`

Comment: what is databasefilepath , how can we make this file , please help

Comment: *what is databasefilepath*  it is a path to sqlite database file made on you mac/PC/whatever and added to your project as asset

Comment: I am using DB Browser for sqlite, here when export its giving option either as json, csv or sql file not as .db file

Comment: As @Selvin mentioned. You should pass your .db file which contains a scheme with some rows. 
In DB Browser for sqlite, if you create New Database, you will find .db extension. I used it many times before.

Comment: can you please let me know the tutorial in linux because i am not able to make .db file in DB Browser for Sqlite

Comment: @Selvin have created a .db file but still, it's not working, the same issue it's not giving any error, I tried debugging as well

Comment: @MustafaKhaled, please help

Comment: @ghufranne have you solved your problem?

Comment: Yes @MustafaKhaled Brother, Thanks for the Help, May Allah bless both of you who came to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the above problem by reinstalling the application, and it also returns a database instance so I was using different instance for the querying database.